# GetByRole Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listbox" and name

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

I have a Kendo dropdown on a react page as follows

```
<div className="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 form-group">
<Label>CDN Code</Label>
<DropDownList
  id="cdnCode-dropdown"
  name="cdnCodeDD"
  value={props.CdnCodeTxt}
  onChange={handleChange}
  data={componentState.cdnCodeList}
  textField="text"
  dataItemKey="id"
  defaultItem={Constants.DefaultItem}
/>
</div>
```

and I have this react test code

```
    test('renders cdncode dropdown', () => {
        render(<ComponentDetailsContent />);
        const element = screen.getByRole("listbox", {
            name: "cdnCodeDD",
        });
        expect(element).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
```

But when I run this test I get this error

`TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "listbox" and name "cdnSicCodeDD"`

It then goes on to list all the accessible roles and the name is blank for all of them.

```
Name "":
      <span
        aria-activedescendant="option-01abe0e8-1cc2-4ca2-ac35-d2a04f7dda62--1"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        aria-owns="0f6115c2-49f9-4430-bb2e-09841d34807b"
        class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"
        id="cdnCode-dropdown"
        role="listbox"
        tabindex="0"
      />
```

Why is that even though my dropdown clearly has a name? I have also tried with "/cdncode/i" and I get the same error. I can't install Testing Playground plugin at work otherwise I would be able to tell the correct query for testing. Any alternatives that don't require chrome plugins?

Also, if I list out all the listboxes using GetAllByRoles I get the following array which contains the dropdown with the correct name?

```
 [...   
    <select aria-hidden="true" name="cdnCodeDD" style="opacity: 0; width: 1px; border: 0px; z-index: -1; position: absolute; left: 50%;" tabindex="-1"><option value="[object Object]" /></select></span>]
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Where does the `DropDownList` come from?

Comment: As mentioned it is a Kendo dropdown, so there is a import { DropDownList } from "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns"; at the top of the file